# How to double foreach with if condition PHP

Tags: php

I'm stuck on a double foreach problem. if I use the "if" function and more than 2 selected data from the database it will duplicate all the data again like:

$notes : { 1 , 2, 3};

$note : { 1 , 2};

> ```
> <?php foreach ($notes as $nts) : ?>
>     <?php foreach ($note as $nt) : ?>
>         <?php if ($nt == $nts['note']) : ?>
>               <option value="<?= $nts['note']; ?>" selected><?= $nts['note']; ?></option>
>         <?php else : ?>
>               <option value="<?= $nts['note']; ?>"><?= $nts['note']; ?></option>
>         <?php endif; ?>
>     <?php endforeach; ?>
> <?php endforeach; ?>
> ```

**The result option**
if 1 and 2 selected then

1
1
2
2
3
3

Can you guys help me ?

Comment: Use `if (in_array($nts['note'], $note)) { ... }` instead of `foreach ($note as $nt) { if ($nt == $nts['note']) { ... } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code like this :

```
<select id="note[]" name="note[]" class="select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select Deficiency" style="width: 100%">
    <?php foreach ($notes as $nts) foreach ($note as $nt) : ?>
        <?php if ($nts['note'] == $nt) : ?>
            <option value="<?= $nts['note']; ?>" selected><?= $nts['note']; ?></option>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php foreach ($notes as $nts) : ?>
        <?php if ($nts['note'] != $nt) : ?>
            <option value="<?= $nts['note']; ?>"><?= $nts['note']; ?></option>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

And the result like :
[Make only the selected double](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaALL.gif)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that every ['notes'] item in the $notes array is being checked against every item in the $note array and an <option... is output whether it is in $note or not. So in the given case, where $note has 2 items in it and $notes has 3 we end up with 6 <option... being output.

Taking @fyrye 's suggestion, we can go through every ['notes'] item in the $notes array and see if it in the $note array. If it is, we output the <option with the selected attribute as well as value, and if it isn't we output the <option with just the value.

Here is the altered code

```
<?php
foreach ($notes as $nts) :
  if (in_array($nts['notes'], $note)) : 
?>
              <option value="<?= $nts['notes']; ?>" selected><?= $nts['notes']; ?></option>
<?php
    else :
?>
              <option value="<?= $nts['notes']; ?>"><?= $nts['notes']; ?></option>
<?php
  endif;
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: it will create a double and deselected list in multitple select